# Automatically execute Redshift SQL code periodically stored on Github using Jenkins

Tags: sql, github, jenkins, automation, amazon-redshift

I have a few reddshift sql scripts on Github which I need to execute in sequence every 30 mins.

e.g.
**At 10:00 am**

script001.sql to be executed first

script002.sql to be executed next and so on...

**At 10:30 am**

script001.sql to be executed first

script002.sql to be executed next and so on...

These scripts run on already existing tables in Redshift. Some of these scripts create tables which are used in the subsequent queries and hence order of execution is important to avoid "Table not found" error.

I have tried:

1. Creating a freestyle project in Jenkins with the following configuration:

General Tab --> GitHub Project and provided a Project URL

Source Code Management Tab --> Selected Git and provided Repository URL in the format https://personaltoken@github.com/site/repo.git

Branches to build Tab --> */main

Build Triggers Tab --> Build periodically (H/30 * * * *)

Now I don't know how to add Build Step to execute the query from GitHub. The configuration builds successfully but obviously does nothing as no steps have been defined.

2. Creating a pipeline project in Jenkins with the same configuration as above but without Pipeline script as I am not sure how to write a pipeline script to run redshift SQL stored on Github

I tried looking for a solution but couldn't find anything for Redshift. There are tutorials and snippets for SQL server and Oracle but their scripts are different and can't be used in Redshift.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.